# Payeezy | Payeezy.js sandbox not working , SSL issue

Tags: payeezy

Payeezy | Payeezy.js  sandbox not working , showing SSL issue Underlying connection was closed , it works fine in live url

How to fix

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself , i was using a windows server dot net solution , and i just upgraded the dotnet frame work to 4.6.1, it support TLS 1.2 by default . Payeezy only support TLS 1.2  now  and it will be updated to live urls from Feb 7 2018

according to them

So now it is got fixed

Some additional points , In sandbox only TLS 1.2 is supported. Any other protocols will cause a handshake failure or SSL error. If you have a .NET/C# integration you should be able to add a line of code to force TLS 1.2, update any system/web config files and additionally you may need to make an update in the Windows registry.

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols(v=vs.110).aspx https://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/